# 2D character tips over sideways after collision with platform

Tags: unity, c#, physics, platformer, collision-resolution

This is what happens when my player character jumps and collides with a platform from the side. The player character tilts over or ends up upside-down or sometimes on its back.

How can I prevent this?

[image: Screenshot of Unity editor showing a rectangular character hitting a platform with its feet, and tilting over]

Comment: What's your desired outcome here? Is it to keep the player vertically oriented at all times, without being able to be knocked over?

Comment: yes, doppelgreener

Comment: looks like you need to freeze the rotations of the rigid body. you can adjust this in code behind or in the inspector at the rigidbody component. Also a helpful note is to parent the player transform to the platform when in contact with it. Especially if both objects can move simultaneously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your character's Rigidbody2D component, expand the "Constraints" fold-out, and tick the "Freeze Rotation Z" box.  This will ensure that physics impacts can't cause your character to spin.

[image]